# Get ReportSource string from mrt file

Tags: c#, reporting, stimulsoft

is it possible to get reportsource string for stiReport from mrt file in stimulsoft?
Or is it possible to load a report from reportSource string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ReportSource property is for internal use. You should not use it.
The Value of the ReportSource is set when you add a report on your form in Visual Studio.